# Организация и ее отдел — через запятую или нет?

Tags: запятые

Если мы пишем название организации и отдел (кафедра, департамент) - нужно ли их разделять запятой?
Например:
Московский государственный университет(,) отдел маркетинга.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Московский государственный университет, экономический факультет, кафедра маркетинга.**

Обособляются слова и словосочетания, **уточняющие** смысл предшествующих слов.

Уточняющие члены (*факультет, кафедра*) по отношению к уточняемым (*университет*) служат наименованиями более конкретными по значению, так как они сужают понятие, передаваемое уточняемым (основным) членом предложения, или в каком-либо плане ограничивают его:
от общего к частному, от широкого к конкретному, от родового к видовому (причём уточняющие члены предложения **всегда следуют за уточняемым**).
Сравните:
*Кафедра маркетинга экономического факультета МГУ* (запятые не требуются).

[Уточняющие члены предложения](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/724-28_utochnyayuschie__poyasnitelnye_i_prisoedinitelnye_chleny_predlozheniya.html)

Answer (score 2):

**Московский государственный университет, отдел маркетинга.**

Запятая (или точка) необходима. То, что без знаков препинания тут не обойтись, видно, как говорится, даже невооруженным взглядом. Можно считать слова "отдел маркетинга" уточняющей конструкцией, такие конструкции по правилам обособляются.

Только есть ли такой отдел в МГУ?

Comment: Возможно там нет такого отдела, это был просто пример. Спасибо.